# How to Solve illegal state Exception in Servelts

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Exception Trace:

> ""java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has
>   been committed
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:328)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
>           at com.zoho.campaign.client.filters.CampaignDomainFilter.doFilter(CampaignDomainFilter.java:140)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>           at com.zoho.campaign.client.filters.CampaignDefaultFilter.doFilter(CampaignDefaultFilter.java:165)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>           at com.adventnet.iam.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:217)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>           at com.adventnet.zoho.crmplus.agent.filter.CRMPlusFilter.doFilter(CRMPlusFilter.java:55)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>           at com.zoho.logs.logclient.filter.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:61)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>           at com.zoho.instrument.InstrumentFilter.doFilter(InstrumentFilter.java:37)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:480)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:240)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

when try to Forward the  RequestDispatcher iam getting this Exception

What is the Reason of this Problem Occurs?

Code:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,ServleResponse res,FilterChain filterchain)thorws IOException,Exception
{
String downloaurl="expired";
boolean is_allow_download=false;
HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest)req;
HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse)res;
RequestDispatcher rd=null;
if(downloadurl.equals("expired"))
    {
    request.setAttribute("isexpire", "expire");
  }
  else if(downloadurl.equals("no_data"))
     {
       request.setAttribute("isdataAval", false);
  }
     if(url1.contains("export.do") && !downloadurl.equals("no_data") && is_allow_download )
       {
         rdc = request.getRequestDispatcher("users/export.do");
         rdc.forward(request, response);
       }
      rdc = request.getRequestDispatcher("users/closed.do"); 
        rdc.forward(request, response);

}
```

Comment: Paste your code here. It is very common mistake. It is saying that control has already returned, so no use of forward().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption of your stack trace, your RS has been committed before you are trying to call forward() method. Your application has returned RS earlier.

p.s. Please add some code snippets for more context.

Comment: @karthik your code fires forward() method two times. it's the wrong way. just add the else block.